# Neo4j fails to bound already existing nodes inside FOREACH

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am loading a chess dataset, where a "snapshot" of a chess board is printed inside a string (FEN). Firstly I use merge on FENs to get all the unique positions as follows:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///xxx/test.csv' AS LINE
FIELDTERMINATOR ';'
MERGE (p:Position { FEN:LINE.FEN })
```

Moving from FEN to FEN, I want to capture some details concerning the player moves as well as the game. But to do this I need to first order the data based on game and moveNumber. This is my cypher code:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///xxx/test.csv' AS LINE
FIELDTERMINATOR ';'
WITH LINE.FEN as FEN,LINE.GameNumber as gn,LINE.MoveNumber as mn,LINE.Side as side,LINE.Move as move
order by gn,mn
WITH COLLECT({FEN:FEN,gID:gn,moveNumber:mn,Side:side,Move:move}) as col
FOREACH(i in RANGE(0, length(col)-2)|
  FOREACH(ps1 in [col[i]] | 
    FOREACH(ps2 in [col[i+1]] |
        FOREACH (ignore in CASE
          WHEN ps1.gID = ps2.gID THEN [1]
          ELSE [] END |
            CREATE UNIQUE (pos1: Position{FEN: ps1.FEN})-[:MOVE{gID:ps2.gID,moveNumber:ps2.moveNumber,Side:ps2.Side,Move:ps2.Move}]->(pos2: Position{FEN: ps2.FEN})
      ))))
```

The response I am receiving is `Unbound Pattern !`, what I translate as "neo4j fails to bound pos1 and pos2 in each case".

To test this out, I used `MERGE` and `CREATE` instead of `CREATE UNIQUE`, and both for some reason recreate all the Position nodes. To make matters worse, the whole pattern is being recreated, instead of a single chain , for each gID, like in this [image (recreated nodes and patterns)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oU0er.png) .

I would really appreciate it, if someone could point me to why this is happening, or address me an alternative approach. I am using neo4j 2.3.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CREATE UNIQUE` is [deprecated](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/deprecations-additions-removals-compatibility/#cypher-deprecations-additions-removals-3.2) and only supported by the also-deprecated legacy Cypher "Rule Planner". It is possible that there are some bugs in the old rule planner causing your issue.

The following query fleshes out the approach indicated by @InverseFalcon (replacing the `CREATE UNIQUE` with 3 `MERGE`s), and simplifies your query structure by eliminating all the `FOREACH` loops.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///xxx/test.csv' AS LINE FIELDTERMINATOR ';'
WITH LINE
ORDER BY LINE.GameNumber, LINE.MoveNumber
WITH COLLECT({FEN: LINE.FEN, gID: LINE.GameNumber, mn: LINE.MoveNumber, Side: LINE.Side, Move: LINE.Move}) as col
UNWIND [i IN RANGE(0, SIZE(col)-2) WHERE col[i].gID = col[i+1].gID | {p1: col[i], p2: col[i+1]}] AS x
MERGE (pos1: Position {FEN: x.p1.FEN})
MERGE (pos2: Position {FEN: x.p2.FEN})
MERGE (pos1)-[m:MOVE {gID: x.p2.gID, moveNumber: x.p2.mn}]->(pos2)
ON CREATE SET m.Side = x.p2.Side, m.Move = x.p2.Move;
```

In this query, I also assume that the `gId` and `moveNumber` properties are sufficient to identify a unique `MOVE` relationship between the same pair of positions.

Comment: Thank you so much. I accept your answer as you provided me with a cleaner solution. And you are right in assuming the part about the uniqueness of the move relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Try using 3 MERGEs instead of the single CREATE UNIQUE.

MERGE pos1, then MERGE pos2, then MERGE the relationship between them.

Comment: Thank you so much for the input. I figured this out literally right before your answer. But instead of trying to merge at the beginning, I merged everything inside the foreach clauses. I appreciate your time in helping me !